# Jquery Flot line graph legend position - can't get it right

Tags: jquery, css, flot

I am having problems positioning the legend in my jquery float graphs. I am trying to follow a working example I have from another web application.

On investigating the style problem inside Firebug I can isolate the problem to the div inside the legend div. There is a difference between the way it appears in my sample and my own web application.

Here is the way the div appears in my sample web application (correct).
[image]

Here is the way the div appears in my sample web application (incorrect) and hence t he legend does not appear properly
[image]

Can someone give me some tips on how to fix this. I've been at it for about 3 hours now. lol.

Just in case here is a link to my javascript.

http://pastebin.com/2WddCRPX

thanking in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting a width. The top one has a width of 73px.

If you position an element absolutely and only set a top OR bottom and a left OR right, and the element is a block level element, then it will take the entire available width up to the next relatively positioned element.

Comment: thank you. that was a birlliant explanation. It helped me solve my issue.